# tensorflow multiplication across dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let tensor `T` has shape `[B, N, N, 6]` and I want to multiply matrices `[b, N, N, 0:3]` by `[b, N, N, 5]` element-wise for each `b in range(B)`. Note, that `[N, N, 4]` should not be changed. What is the best way to do this using tensorflow?

My attempts:

`result = tf.empty([B, N, N, 5])
for b in range(B):
  for i in range(4)
    result[b, :, :, i] = tf.mul(T[b, :, :, i], T[b, :, :, 5])
  result[b, :, :, 4] = T[b, :, :, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow, it's not generally possible to build a tensor value by assigning to slices. The programming model tends to be more functional than imperative. One way of implementing your calculation is as follows:

```
result = tf.concat(3, [tf.mul(T[:, :, :, 0:4], T[:, :, :, 5:6]), T[:, :, :, 4:5]])
```

Note that you don't need multiple multiplications, because (i) the original computation is already element-wise on the 0th dimension (`for b in range(B)`), and (ii) TensorFlow will broadcast the second argument to the multiplication in the 3rd dimension.